# Does AWS guarantee my lambda function will be triggered 100%?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I set up my AWS workflow so that my lambda function will be triggered when a text file is added to my S3 bucket, and generally, it worked fine - when I upload a bunch of text files to the S3 bucket, a bunch of lambda will be running at the same time and process each text file.

But my issue is that occasionally, 1 or 2 files (out of 20k or so in total) did not trigger the lambda function as expected. I have no idea why - when I checked the logs, it's NOT that the file is processed by the lambda but failed. The log showed that the lambda was not trigger by that 1 or 2 files at all. I don't believe it's reaching the 1000 concurrent lambda limitation as well since my function runs faster and the peak is around 200 lambdas.

My question is: is this because AWS lambda does not guarantee it will be triggered 100%? Like the S3, there is always a (albeit tiny) possibility of failure? If not, how can I debug and fix this issue?

Comment: AWS never guarantees 100% on any service. The maximum guarantee rate is 99,99%.  Anyway, lambda usually works fine. What are the rules for your trigger?

Comment: Did you check if your function is not being throttled? Check the Throttling Behaviour for more info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html#throttling-behavior

Comment: Hi @Stargazer, the trigger is the event of one file been uploaded to S3. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Hi @ThalesMinussi, yes I did and the max I reached is ~20% of the limitation (1000 concurrent lambda running).

Comment: @Stargazer They do guarantee 100% on Route53

Comment: my understanding is that each s3 PUT triggers a lambda invoke, but it may be worth making sure you loop over the Records structure you receive in case 2 files resulted in a single invocation (again, unlikely but may be worth checking :)

Comment: Hi @xpa1492 That's a good idea! Do you know how to check if this is happening?

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention how long the Lambdas take to execute. The default limit of [concurrent executions is 1000](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html). If you are uploading files faster than they can be processed with 1000 Lambdas then you'll want to reach out to AWS support and get your limit increased.

Also from [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html):

> Amazon S3 event notifications typically deliver events in seconds but can sometimes take a minute or longer. On very rare occasions, events might be lost.
>
> If your application requires particular semantics (for example, ensuring that no events are missed, or that operations run only once), we recommend that you account for missed and duplicate events when designing your application. You can audit for missed events by using the LIST Objects API or Amazon S3 Inventory reports. The LIST Objects API and Amazon S3 inventory reports are subject to eventual consistency and might not reflect recently added or deleted objects.

Comment: Hi @Andy, good point. Each of my lambda takes less than 1 min. I don't believe it's throttled. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Hi @Andy, Thanks for pointing the detail from the documentation! Now I tend to believe that I am having these rare occasions.